# I can't figure out why my buttons are not appearing on my Android VM?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, button, imagebutton

I am trying to configure my button layouts and cannot figure out why the buttons are not visible despite the lack of errors. I have tinkered around and at best only am able to get a single button to show much less all of them. Each image button references an image stored in drawable-ldpi, and each are roughly 1 KB in size.

Below is the intended layout look:

```
 _______________________
|        logo          |
|______________________|
|       search         |
|______________________|
|                      |
|     featured         |
|                      |
|______________________|
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|____|_____|_____|_____|
|     advertisement    |
|______________________|
```

Android main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="45" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mytastelogo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:src="@drawable/mytastelogo_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/featuredpanel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="45" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mycollection"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/mycollection_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myrecommendations"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/myrecommendations_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/topitems"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/topitems_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/randomitem"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/randomitem_image" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/advertisement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set heights and widths with 0 dps. You won't see anything. try to solve those 0dps first.

Comment: The 0 dp allows the weight to control the size of the features, at least from what i understand.

Comment: Not really! Change those 0dp to match-parent and play with the weights.